# Problem with use 2 translations at 1 function Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function in which I need to make 3 translations for the Russian and English versions. I have done it simply:

```
'message' => trans('notify.craft_win') .$summa. trans('notify.craft_wumm') trans('notify.craft_chance') .$chance. '%',
```

but i received error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'trans' (T_STRING), expecting ']'`

`%` it's static word, without translate.

Where can be my mistake?

Comment: Think you just missed a `.`?

Comment: ```'message' => trans('notify.craft_win') .$summa. trans('notify.craft_wumm'). trans('notify.craft_chance') .$chance. '%',```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing a dot:

```
//                                                                      v
'message' => trans('notify.craft_win').$summa.trans('notify.craft_wumm').trans('notify.craft_chance').$chance.'%',
```

Comment: thank you, so much!